# Is it possible to make a reference to a subdocument on Mongoose (MongoDB)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say I have this collection named `users`:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5371251fdd16203032846873"),
"address" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("537505bb6c12480d0b2038c6")
        "type" : "Main",
        "street" : "Bla bla street",
        "number" : "132",
        "complement" : "",
        "district" : "Bla bla district",
        "zipcode" : "somezipcode",
        "state" : "BLA",
        "city" : "Bla bla city"
    }
]
```

And then I have this one called `orders` where I want to have the `address` field, in which I would like to store the ID so I could use Mongoose's `populate` method to `join`the collections with one another, like this:

`address: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "???"}`

Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't seen any documentations or examples of that usecase, though, if i had to guess, i'd say if it were possible, you would use `ref: "users.address"`

Comment: You may end up having to break Address into it's own collection.

Comment: i definitely wouldn't recommend breaking address into its own collection, more often then not you'll want to retrieve address alongside user data

Comment: @KevinB It would be messy. If it comes to that, I'd rather repeat the address in the order collection.

Comment: I'd rather not do it that way either, and instead just handle the extra query work myself. (store address id on order, find address within user collection by address id)

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't store a `ref` to the address, you'd store a ref to 'User'

`user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}`

Because the address is under the user key. Then you can retrieve the address via `order.user.address` which is still only one populate because address is embedded in the user document.

I also wouldn't get in the habit of calling these joins, because they're not. They're just a second round trip to the database, so you should avoid these like the plague whenever possible.

An alternative solution might be just storing `userAddress` as an embedded document on the `order` model if you need to access this often

Comment: Yeh, but I really need it this time, else the could would get very messy and redundant. I don't have a model of the subcollection, let me add one and try this.

Comment: oh - hey i totally misread your quesiton. you wouldn't store a ref to the address, you'd store a ref to 'User' because the address is under the user key. then you can retrieve the address via `order.user.address` which is still only one populate because address is embedded in the user

Comment: all subdocuments are implicitly populated when you populate a reference in mongodb because it requires no extra queries to the database. this is kind of the point of mongodb ;)

Comment: The problem is that an `User` can have multiple `adresses`, but an `order` must be linked to a single `address`.

Comment: in that case i'd say your best bet is to embed the actual address on the order document. alternatively you can give objectid values to each item in the user's `address` array and then store that on the order, populate the user and then search the addresses for that id, but i think the former is actually a better conceptual model, aside from better performance

edit: also mongoose already does the array _id thing for you unless you explicitly disable it

Comment: @ComicSansMSLover did you come to a resolution on this

Comment: Things got kinda crazy here yesterday. I'm looking into it right now, will answer back when I'm done.

Comment: So, hey, I finally tried to make it work, but it didn't. There was no way to make reference to the subdocument with populate. It would simply return me null.

Comment: can I see the updated code (edit your post). you don't populate the address - you populate 'user' and the address will be there in the populated version